# Why does using char math result in unexpected results in C++?

Tags: c++, math, char, unsigned

I have a function that I am having a hard time understanding how the math is being performed:

```
    unsigned long Fat_AuthAnswer(char b1, char b2, char b3, char b4)`
    {
    unsigned char* ptr = NULL;
    unsigned short StartCRC = b1 + b2*256;
    unsigned long ret = crcbuf(StartCRC, b3, &AuthBlock[b4]);
        ret = (ret & 0x0000ffff) | (crcbuf(StartCRC, b4, &AuthBlock[b3])<<16);
    }
```

With b1=0xAF b2=0x50

When the function is executed StartCRC = b1 + b2*256; Yields StartCRC = 0x4FAF

I would have expected the results for StartCRC to be 0x50AF.

My question is why does it seem that b2 is reduced by one?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems `char` in your environment is signed and the value `0xAF` is sign-extended to value line `0xFFFFFFAF`. This will cause that `0xFF` is added to tha part of `b2` and therefore it looks like `b2` is reduced by one.

You should cast `b1` to `unsigned char` to avoid this.

```
    unsigned short StartCRC = static_cast<unsigned char>(b1) + b2*256;
```

Comment: Mike Thanks for the response. That is exactly what it was.